# Pop-up in tizen web project

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I'm trying to implement pop-up feature in tizen web project. Here is the code. This is a link, when we click on the link, a pop-up should open.

```
            <a href="#div" data-rel="back">
                About Us!
            </a>
            <div id="popup" data-role="popup" class="center_title_1btn">
                <div class="ui-popup-title">
                    <h1>About Us!</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-popup-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. 
                Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis 
                parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, 
                ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla 
                consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, 
                aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut,
                imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede
                mollis pretium.</div>
                <div class="ui-popup-button-bg">
                    <a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Button</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

But pop-up isn't opening. How can I rectify it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `href="#popup"` instead of `href="#div"`.

The `href` attribute in the `a` element must point to the popup `id` which is its unique identifier.